# Compare between source table and staging table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am loading my Employee table from source to staging area like below :

[image]

The SRC contains a T-SQL query :

```
SELECT EmpId,Firstname,Lastname,DeptId,Email,PhoneNumber From dbo.Employee
```

The Lookup is like below : (Redirect to no match output)
[image]

- The Lookup No Match Output : Insert new records in the staging table
  Employee
- The Lookup Match Output : Update the old records with the news coming
  from Source

Example :

```
EmpId Firstname Lastname DeptId Email PhoneNumber
55    Alex      Yves     3      NULL  NULL
```

If EmpId doesn't exist in the STG table it will be added.
If EmpId=55 has updates in the source like below  :

```
EmpId Firstname Lastname DeptId Email            PhoneNumber
55    Alex      Yves     3      alex@company.com +1234567
```

Once the update is detected after the Lookup Match Output since the EmpId exists already , the update will affect only EmpId=55 and not all the existing ones like I did.

I want to update only the records that have updates. How can I detect the updates for an Employee existing already in the STG table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you question, you would need to change the lookup component in two ways:

- change the cache option to no cache
- In the connection tab, use a SQL query to Union the employeeids from the target table and the stage table

This solution will be really slow for a few reasons:

- the no cache option will query target and stage table for each row
- updates are executed for each row
- you'll probably have frequent deadlocks between the 3 components

A better performing solution would be to insert all the records into the stage table and then use an execute sql task to insert and update the target table.